# Cannot set property 'style' of null

Tags: javascript, html5

Хочу, чтобы при разных вариантах а/б-теста страницы выдавались разные картинки фона в конструкторе сайтов. Реализация такова, что пришлось писать JS.

Выдает ошибку Cannot set property 'style' of null. Перерыл кучу статей, но однозначного ответа не нашел. Вроде все правильно пишу.

Подскажите, в чем причина?

```
<script> 
  if (window.plp_content_id == 1944603) { 
    document.getElementById("ab_test").style="background-image: url(../img/boy-1-v2.jpg)";
  } else { 
    document.getElementById("ab_test").style="background-image: url(../img/boy-1-v4.jpg)";
  } 
</script>
```

Comment: Осмелюсь спросить банальную вещь - Вы id то элементу назначили? На всякий случай проверьте, может глаз_замылился\ замотались\забыли?

Comment: Ошибка говорит Вам о том, что Вы не можете определить свойство `style` пустому значению. В смысле `document.getElementById("ab_test")` не находит элемент

Comment: Вот простой рабочий пример - https://codepen.io/qwerty_wasd/pen/WyVNvE
Попробуйте написать вместо `#ab_test` ->  `.ab_test` и посмотрите в консоль.

Answer (score 0):

Задан не правильный путь к Img, то есть img возвращает null

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).